# Computing Average Grade

Tags: php, mysqli, datatable

I'm trying to compute an average based on the table data that will out. How can I echo a zero if there is no data until the user insert it?

Here's what I have done.

```
                                              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_final_grade)){ 
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                                                    <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['grade']; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                                <?php
                                                    global $total4, $sum4, $average4;
                                                     $total4+=$row['grade'];
                                                     $sum4++;
                                                    } ?>
                                        </table> 
                                        <?php $average4=($total4/$sum4);
                                            $average4 = number_format($average4, 0, '.', '');
                                         ?>
                                            AVERAGE GRADE: <?php echo $average4; ?>
```

If there's no table data, the average is equal to 0, but when there is table data, the average should be computed.

Comment: `$result_final_grade->num_rows`  will return the number of rows in the result, check if the num rows is more than 0 then execute the while, otherwise echo 0

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. Just initialize the `$total4`, `$sum4`, and `$average4` variables to zero before the loop. You shouldn't need that `global` line, and even if you do it shouldn't be inside the while loop. (The closing `</tbody>` tag probably shouldn't be either.)

```
<?php

// initialize your variables before the loop
$total4 = 0;
$sum4 = 0;
$average4 = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_final_grade)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?php echo $row['grade']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $total4 += $row['grade'];
    $sum4++;
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then check the row count. If it's not zero, calculate the average.

```
<?php
if ($sum4) {
    $average4 = $total4/$sum4;
}
$average = number_format($average4, 0, '.', '');
?>
AVERAGE GRADE: <?php echo $average4; ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome! :-) I changed it a bit just now, thought it might be a bit easier to read if we set `$average4` to zero at the beginning as well.